# React & Formik : how to send back sucess or failure from sucess handler to the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

It's about formik (react & typescript).

I managed to make some code working but I used `.bind(this)` for that. I really think there's a better way to do things, so here I am to ask.

Here is the code:

```
  public register(values: IRegistrationForm, { setSubmitting, setFieldError }: FormikActions<IRegistrationForm>) {
    axios
      .post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/register', values)
      .then(response => {
        this.success(); // fail without the bind(this)
        setSubmitting(false);
      });
  }

  private formik() {
    // I need to bind this to be able to call some methods of my component
    const register = this.register.bind(this);
    return (
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            email: '',
            password: '',
          }}
          onSubmit={register}
          render= {this.formRender}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string().email().required(),
            password: Yup.string().min(10).required(),
          })}
        />
    );
  }
```

If it helps (not sure) the whole code is here: https://gist.github.com/Nek-/c4ccb6b76593d71105c29079c48757f0

Answer (score 1):

It's better to bind your event handler, component functions that shares the class context with `this` keyword in the constructor. not in your render function.

```
constructor(props:Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      success: null,
    };
    //... bind your methods here.
    this.register = this.register.bind(this)
}
```

or use the fat arrow functions it will auto bind `this` and avoid binding in your render or in your constructor.

```
public register = (values: IRegistrationForm, { setSubmitting, setFieldError }: FormikActions<IRegistrationForm>) => {
 // your function body.
}

private success = () => {
    this.setState({...this.state, success: true});
}
```

You can use it with your `fomik` function or any event handlers function that needs to share `this` context.

Comment: Well, Id like to avoid it, not to change the method. Also this makes no sense to me to prepare a method to be bind to this while... It's actually the default behavior !

Comment: I was expected an answer that could really help me to forward information to the "previous" component. But your solution is an actual thing. Tested, worked. Thank you.